# Grouping queryset by column value

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a queryset that returns Tasks by client id from the following models and would like to get some more filters to receive more precised data. Models are just a example structure of what I am trying to achieve:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Office(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    clientid = models.ForeignKey(Client, db_constraint=False, db_index=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    officeid = models.ForeignKey(Office, db_constraint=False, db_index=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    areaid = models.ForeignKey(Area, db_constraint=False, db_index=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

The query that I am using: `Task.objects.filter(areaid__officeid__clientid='1')`

It returns long queryset that I need to group by `areaid`. By grouping I mean receiving for example list of few querysets that contain only Tasks for single `areaid`. Is there a possibility to achieve this by django orm without looping through queryset I already have? I need this to render different tables in jinja2, unique table for each `areaid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a QuerySet on `Area` with `prefetch_related`.

```
areas = Area.objects.prefetch_related('task_set')
for area in areas:
    area_tasks = area.task_set.all()
```